# Efficient way of creating a matrix of overlapping positions using GRanges

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have a list of genomic windows (see example below) and I am trying to determine what positions of each window overlap with a series of Chip-Seq peaks from different samples. My goal is to evaluate the positions falling within a peak across all these samples, so I create a matrix of 1's and 0's where rows are samples and columns are genomic positions. Therefore, matrices have as many columns as positions in the window.

```
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames               ranges strand
         <Rle>            <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]    chr22 [16056636, 16057635]      *
  [2]    chr22 [16847853, 16848852]      *
  [3]    chr22 [16848853, 16849852]      *
  [4]    chr22 [16849853, 16850852]      *
  [5]    chr22 [16850853, 16851852]      *
  [6]    chr22 [16851853, 16852852]      *
```

Thus, on the one hand I have a `grwindows` GRanges object and on the other a GRangesList containing one GRange object for each sample. At the moment I generate these matrices window by window in an extremely inefficient way that involves multiple loops.

```
for (window in 1:nwin) { # nwin: number of windows
    matpeaks <- matrix(0,nrow=length(samples),ncol=wsize) # wsize: window size
    for (sample in samples) { # We add every sample to the matrix
      newrow <- numeric(wsize)
      grwin <- grwindows[window]
      grpeaks <- grlist[[sample]] # GRangesList object}
      overlap <- findOverlaps(query=grwin,subject=grpeaks)
      spans <- ranges(overlap,ranges(grwin),ranges(grpeaks)) # Ranges of the overlap
      if (length(spans) > 0) {
        for (i in 1:length(spans)) { # Peaks overlapping that window
           newrow[(start(spans[i])-start(grwin)):(end(spans[i])-start(grwin))] <- 1
        }
      }  
      matpeaks[sample,] <- newrow
    }
 }
```

I am not very familiar with GRanges and not experienced in R programming, so I hope you can help me optimize this chunk of code. I have come up with something that slightly reduces the execution time, but there are still too many `for` loops and the improvement is very limited:

```
for (window in 1:nwin) {
  grwin <- grwindows[window]
  fun <- function(x) {overlap <- findOverlaps(query=grwin,subject=x); spans <- ranges(overlap,ranges(grwin),ranges(x))}
  spans <- lapply(grlist,fun)
  for (sam in 1:nrow(matpeaks)) {
    if (length(spans[[sam]]) > 0) {
      for (i in 1:length(spans[[sam]])) {
        matpeaks[sam,(start(spans[[sam]][i])-start(grwin)):(end(spans[[sam]][i])-start(grwin))] <- 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your attention and I hope I have made myself understood.